# New iPhone XS People & Places People album not populating - nothing

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

I have a new iPhone Xs running iOS 12.4 syncing to MBP using Mojave 10.14.6 via iTunes version 12.9.5.5. Using usb cord to sync selected items - pics, music, etc..

The People album under People & Places will not populate.  Can anyone help to get it working?  Not sure what to do.  Here is a pic of how it looks now.  Have left the phone locked and plugged into power outlet days at a time and nothing shows in album.

Interestingly, the 5 has now changed to 7 pictures synced when I now look at the phone. It changed after I took these 2 screen shots to post....  Weird.

[image]  [image]  [image]

Comment: Are you using iCloud Photo Library?

Comment: No. Pictures are synced from a picture directory then sub-folders off C:/ drive selected in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Photos synced through iTunes won't carry over faces data. Instead, your phone will scan the library manually. It will do this in such a fashion that it doesn't interfere with your battery life.

If you haven't left it plugged in over night you certainly won't see much results

Comment: Tks. See my description above - days and hours at a time. Won’t add to the people album.

Comment: Not sure why it's going so slow. Have you tried restarting your phone since you've seen this?

Comment: yes. also did restart hitting the 3 buttons in a row and holding the last one until the apple logo comes up - cant remember if they call it a hard reset(start) or what....

Comment: so i finally tried deleting he ipod photo cache and synched again then restarted the phone then locked it on power and left it alone.  1 day later had 5 people and no more scanning msg.  Not sure why there are only 5 people - before i had 10 or so.....  Anyhow i then synced the phone to back it up and it found 800 more pics from somewhere and took 20 minutes to show any activity on syncing then another 15  minutes to finish.  I have since tried to sync again - another 30 minutes from start to finish and another found 400 photos.  Clld apple and they are aware of syncing and photos issue!!

Comment: not bad - 7 days, multiple calls to apple and many hours setting a new phone that still doesnt work properly.  I give up......

Comment: back again to being stuck on updating people.....

Comment: still only 5 people.....  this stinks